# What is the recommended way to autoscale a service based on open http connections

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I have an EKS cluster in AWS where a specific service will work as a live feed to clients, I expect it to use very low resources but it will be using server-sent event which require long lived http connections. Given I will be serving thousands of users I believe the best metric to auto scaling would be open connections.

My understanding is that k8s only have cpu and memory usage as out of the box metrics for scaling, I may be wrong here. I looked into custom metrics but k8s documentation on that is extremely shallow.

Any sugestions or guidance on this is very welcome.